# Some schematic voltage values (physical names) missed when printed or generated in Altium

Tags: pcb-design, schematics, output, documentation

Maybe it's a silly issue, but the fact is that I don' t know why a voltage value is present in the schem project document but it will disappear from the destination document (printed or generated) at placed power port elements.

More strange issue is that it is not happening to every power port name. Some ports keeps the voltage value.

It' s something strange, but I would like to show all the port values on output documents. So I would like to know what the issue is and try to fix it.

[image]

Left picture is the schem view in project with name.schDoc. If I print it directly or if I generate a schem output file, hence, right pict you will see.

Someone says it could be an Altium bug. But I will ask for people here, hopping that someone face the same issue sometime and they could solve it.

Any trick to see the "removed" names when printing? Any information will be apreciated.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Which version of Altium?

I came across this bug in AD17. It notably affects only right and top side net orientation. The workaround involves text rendering in the Schematic preferences.

Go to your DXP preferences and uncheck the GDI text rendering box.

[image]

Sincerely,

Martin

Comment: Great! That works!